# Laravel 6.0 - Custom email verification: temporarySignedRoute() URL not working with new route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-6

I'm trying to upgrade to Laravel 6 from 5.8. We're using a custom verification email `Notification` with the following code to get the verification URL:

```
URL::temporarySignedRoute(
    'verification.verify', 
    Carbon::now()->addMinutes(60), 
    [
        'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
    ]
);
```

This seems to generate an URL that does not work with the new route ([check this](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#email-verification-route-change)), for example:

```html
http://host/email/verify/38?expires=1574602925&signature=4410c2230623619633be56d3641814cea3c77236bf8435cba88fc102a35d3dc4
```

I couldn't find anything on that specific topic online so far, so I'd appreciate any help to get this to work in Laravel 6.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution in:

`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/VerifyEmail.php`

Had to change the code to:

```
return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
    'verification.verify',
    Carbon::now()->addMinutes(60),
    [
        'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
        'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
    ]
);
```

Comment: are we hashing the email address here?

Comment: I run into this issue after implement above: 
Method Illuminate\Translation\Translator::getFromJson does not exist.
I've tried php artisan view:clear, but same error appear again. Any advice?

Comment: Update: Solve it by changing from:
Lang::getFromJson()
To: 
Lang::get()

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed yes

Comment: WARNING!!! You should NEVER change any files in the `vendor` folder!

Comment: comment deleted

Comment: @Peter, I didn't mean to say anybody should change files in `vendor`, I only said that I found the solution for my problem there

Answer (score 0):

you can insert into AppServiceProvider->boot:

```
public function boot()
 {
      VerifyEmail::toMailUsing(function ($notifiable) {
          $verifyUrl = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
              'verification.verify', Carbon::now()->addMinutes(60),
              [
                  'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
                  'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
              ]
          );
          return (new MailMessage)->subject('Welcome!')->markdown('emails.verify', ['url' => $verifyUrl]);
      });
 }
```

see email template is in views/emails/verify.blade.php