# Missing required parameters for [Route: verification.verify] [URI: {locale}/email/verify/{id}/{hash}]

Tags: laravel, verification

In registration process, while sending verification email issue with adding {locale}.
Data is being added to database. But thereafter giving following issue.

Missing required parameters for [Route: verification.verify] [URI: {locale}/email/verify/{id}/{hash}].

I think it will be some type of overriding the verification process.

## web.php

```
Route::group([
  'prefix' => '{locale}', 
  'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'], 
  'middleware' => 'setlocale'], function() {
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect(app()->getLocale());
});
```

## vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php

```
$this->get('email/verify/{id}/{hash}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
```

I know in router {locale}  is not matching with the routing. But how to resolve this?

Comment: Show your web.php file code? and `Route: verification.verify` link code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);` just use `Auth::routes();` and manually add these routes:

```
Route::get('email/verify', 'Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
Route::get('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');

Route::group([ 'prefix' => '{locale}', 'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'], 'middleware' => 'setlocale'], function() { 
    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home'); 
});
```

check [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52745390/9978078).

Comment: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
on register itself.
Any suggestion?

Comment: On which URL you're getting it ? make it method `Route::post`

Comment: The `verification.resend` route should be `post`, [at least in laravel/ui](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/3.x/src/AuthRouteMethods.php#L93). `verification.verify` also [requires `/{hash}`](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/3.x/src/AuthRouteMethods.php#L92) on the end now.

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 6 and 7 the verification.verify route is

```
'email/verify/{id}/{hash}'
```

Answer (score 0):

[Laravel 6.0 - Custom email verification: temporarySignedRoute() URL not working with new route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59018355/laravel-6-0-custom-email-verification-temporarysignedroute-url-not-working)

Check this out if you're having this because for me it was a custom verify link

Comment: Inside the file vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/VerifyEmail.php

Check to see if you have: 'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}',  'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'], 'middleware' => 'setlocale'], function() {
    
    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

});
Route::get('email/verify', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController::class,'show'])->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController::class,'verify'])->name('verification.verify');
Route::post('email/resend', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController::class,'resend'])->name('verification.resend');
```

Resend should be Post method!
This works in Laravel 8.0

Answer (score 0):

open your verify.blade.php file

```
{{ route('verification.resend') }}
```

replace with

```
{{ route('verification.resend', app()->getlocale()) }}
```